# Facebook connect log in button is not working on iOS 5

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect). When I click on the "Log In" button of the Facebook dialog, it just disappears like normal, but not Login.

If I log in through a device and then press the Go button of the keyboard and if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the simulator after entering my username and password that it has successfully logged in but not by clicking on the "Log In" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say Facebook Connect, I assume you're referring to the current version of the Facebook SDK outlined at *[iOS Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)*.

If so, can you confirm that your `FBSessionDelegate` method `fbDidLogin` is getting called? (Put a logging message or debugging breakpoint there and confirm that this is the case.)

If it's not getting called, that can happen if you don't put this code in your application delegate, but rather have it in some other object.

Comment: By the way, I'm an advocate of changing the authorize method in Facebook.m to say `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];`. I find that the FB app is good about returning to the app, but in the absence of that, but Safari isn't, so by turning off the safariAuth option, I end up with an in-app web browser window, so I don't lose the user as they get transferred to Safari in the absence of the Facebook app being installed on their device.